# how do i loop thru an array which assigned in a "it" block

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

i like to iterate through an array and execute some testcases which is assigned in an "it" block. i tried but node says "a" is not defined which is true so apparently thats what i needed accessing a variable from mocha into node. Is there any way to make it work?

```
it('',function(done){
"this it block generates array "a" dynamically "
done();
})

a.forEach(function(i){
it(i,function(done){
console.log(i)
done();
})
})
```

Comment: define array `a` in your `describe()` block...not an `it()` block.

Comment: i get a dynamic data from the "it" block in an array, i didn't posted my full code. i could hav done it if i knew the array "a" but it generates a utomatically in that "it" block.

Answer (score 0):

Each test case (`it` block) block should be independent and not rely on side-effect from a different test case.

What you can do is define a `beforeEach` block and initialize the array there

```
describe('...', function() {
  var a = [];

  beforeEach(function() {
    a = initArraySomehow()
  });

  it('', function() {
    // a is now initialized
  });
});
```